# Refresh listbox after adding

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a `listbox` in C# and want it to refresh after I added a new item(which gets opened with a new form dialog)

Here is my code which doesn't work.

```
    private void showAllItems()
    {
        itemList = Db.getAllItems();
        lb_itemList.DataSource = itemList;
    }

    private void showItemPreview(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string curItem = lb_itemList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        briefPreviewList = Db.getItemBriefPreview(curItem);
        string itemInfos = string.Join(",", briefPreviewList.ToArray());
        string[] infos = itemInfos.Split(',');
        l_itemDB.Text = curItem;
        l_CategoryDB.Text = infos[0];
    }

    private void b_addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int uid = 1;
        AddItem addItemForm = new AddItem(uid);
        addItemForm.ShowDialog();
        CurrencyManager cm = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[itemList];
        cm.Refresh();

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean `my code which doesn't work`? Does the `ListBox`not update, or do you get an exception or what?

Comment: @nolonar - The listbox doesn't update, but no exception. But the answer from cr41g14 helpd :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume when you insert a new item it gets stored into the database, if this is the case then all you need to do is reset the datasource:

```
private void b_addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int uid = 1;
    AddItem addItemForm = new AddItem(uid);
    addItemForm.ShowDialog();
    addItemForm.Dispose();

    this.showAllItems();
 }
```

Comment: Ah, the dispose function helped me a lot thank you very much :)